# Syntax required for conditional variable use to modify SQL query in Node.JS

Tags: sql, node.js

I've fairly new to NodeJS, and I'm not sure of the best method or syntax to create an MS SQL query with conditional code. Here's what I want to do, with the query greatly simplified, and using some pseudocode:

```
// @route   GET /api/flow/data/references
async function getDataReferences(req, res) {
  const { station, type } = req.query

  let pool
  try {
    pool = await sql.connect(config)
    const { recordset } = await pool
      .request()
      .input('station', sql.NVarChar(50), station).query`
      SELECT Reference
      FROM TABLE 
      WHERE Status = 'Done' ` +
        if(type === 1) {
          `AND Station_1 = @station`
        } else if(type === 2) {
            `AND Station_2 = @station`
        } else {
            `AND Station_3 = @station`
        }
    + `AND Process = 5`

    const processedData = recordset.map((item) => item.Reference)

    res.json(processedData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      `ERROR with Station: ${station} with Type: ${type}`,
      error.message,
      new Date()
    )
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  } finally {
    await pool.close()
  }
}
```

Depending on the value of "type" supplied to the function, I want the query to reference a different DB column.

**UPDATE:**
So I've found that the following works, although arguably the formatting isn't quite as nice.

```
// @route   GET /api/flow/data/references
async function getDataReferences(req, res) {
  const { station, type } = req.query
    let station_column
    if(type === 1) {
        station_column = 'AND Station_1 = @station'
      } else if(type === 2) {
        station_column = 'AND Station_2 = @station'
      } else {
        station_column = 'AND Station_3 = @station'
      }

  let query = `
        SELECT Reference
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE Status = 'Done' 
        ${station_column}
        AND Process = 5`

  let pool
  try {
    pool = await sql.connect(config)
    const { recordset } = await pool
      .request()
      .input('station', sql.NVarChar(50), station).query(query)

    const processedData = recordset.map((item) => item.Reference)

    res.json(processedData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      `ERROR with Station: ${station} with Type: ${type}`,
      error.message,
      new Date()
    )
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  } finally {
    await pool.close()
  }
}
```

I tried just using the template literal substitutions directly in the query, but that wouldn't work. (Perhaps for reasons stated here: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals )

If I don't get any better answer, I'll post this as the answer; but would like to know if there's a best practice method for doing this.

Comment: In stead of the nested `if`, you could alo use the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: @Luuk - Yeah, typically if there's 4+ if/else then I'd use a switch, but that's not really my question here. I was hoping for a way to have the logic in-line in the query. (Because on 30+ line queries, with multiple bits of logic, it gets more complicated if you have to follow the variables vs. having it all in-line with the SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems like this works, and isn't overly complicated:**

```
// @route   GET /api/flow/data/references
async function getDataReferences(req, res) {
  const { station, type } = req.query
    let station_column
    if(type === 1) {
        station_column = 'AND Station_1 = @station'
      } else if(type === 2) {
        station_column = 'AND Station_2 = @station'
      } else {
        station_column = 'AND Station_3 = @station'
      }

  let query = `
        SELECT Reference
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE Status = 'Done' 
        ${station_column}
        AND Process = 5`

  let pool
  try {
    pool = await sql.connect(config)
    const { recordset } = await pool
      .request()
      .input('station', sql.NVarChar(50), station).query(query)

    const processedData = recordset.map((item) => item.Reference)

    res.json(processedData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      `ERROR with Station: ${station} with Type: ${type}`,
      error.message,
      new Date()
    )
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
  } finally {
    await pool.close()
  }
}
```

Essentially, create the full query string in advance, including the parameters to bind, and then pull that whole string in as the query.